# Search function only works on the first page and not on other pagination pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

The search box that I have added to my table is only working on the first page and not on the other pagination pages. I want it to show the search result from the entire table. And I also want to show the current page row count before the total page row count. You can see it at the bottom of the page. It will be really helpful if the expert helps me out with this.

```js
    // Table Search Script Starts 
        function myFunction() {
            var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, pagination;
            input = document.getElementById("myInput");
            filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
            table = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
            tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
                alltags = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
                isFound = false;
                for (j = 0; j < alltags.length; j++) {
                    td = alltags[j];
                    if (td) {
                        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
                        if (txtValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "";
                            j = alltags.length;
                            isFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (!isFound && tr[i].className !== "header") {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }

        }


     // Table Search Script Ends 
     
      // Table Pagination Script Starts 
     const paginationNumbers = document.getElementById("pagination-numbers");
    const pageCount_ele = document.getElementById("pageCount") // Handle the page values
    const currentPage_ele = document.getElementById("currentPage")
    const paginatedList = document.getElementById("paginated-list");
    const listItems = paginatedList.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
    const nextButton = document.getElementById("next-button");
    const prevButton = document.getElementById("prev-button");

    const paginationLimit = 2;
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(listItems.length / paginationLimit);
    let currentPage = 1;

    const disableButton = (button) => {
        button.classList.add("disabled");
        button.disable = true;
    };

    const enableButton = (button) => {
        button.classList.remove("disabled");
        button.disable = false;
    };

    const handlePageButtonsStatus = () => {
        if (currentPage === 1) {
            disableButton(prevButton);
        } else {
            enableButton(prevButton);
        }

        if (pageCount === currentPage) {
            disableButton(nextButton);
        } else {
            enableButton(nextButton);
        }
    };

    const handleActivePageNumber = () => {

        currentPage_ele.innerText = currentPage
        
        enableButton(prevButton) // Assing them as clickable
        enableButton(nextButton)
        
        if (currentPage == pageCount){
            disableButton(nextButton) // if last page disable next

        }
        if (currentPage == 1){
            disableButton(prevButton) // if 1st disable prev
        }
    };

    const appendPageNumber = (index) => {
        const pageNumber = document.createElement("button");
        pageNumber.className = "pagination-number";
        pageNumber.innerHTML = index;
        pageNumber.setAttribute("page-index", index);
        pageNumber.setAttribute("aria-label", "Page " + index);

        paginationNumbers.appendChild(pageNumber);
    };

    const getPaginationNumbers = () => {
        
    };

    const setCurrentPage = (pageNum) => {
        currentPage = pageNum;

        handleActivePageNumber();
        handlePageButtonsStatus();

        const prevRange = (pageNum - 1) * paginationLimit;
        const currRange = pageNum * paginationLimit;

        listItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.classList.add("hidden");
            if (index >= prevRange && index < currRange) {
                item.classList.remove("hidden");
            }
        });
    };

    window.addEventListener("load", () => {
        getPaginationNumbers();
        setCurrentPage(1);

        prevButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
        });

        nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
        });
        pageCount_ele.innerText = pageCount
    });
  
    // Table Pagination Script Ends
```

```css
   .result {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
      .canel-trains-grids {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel {
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel span {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #34A853;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        width: auto;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel {
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel label {
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 39px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input {
        width: 230px;
        height: 22px;
        border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
        float: right;
    }
    
    .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
    

 /* Responsive Table Start */
    
    .rstable {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 16px 0px;
    }
    
    .rstable table {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    
    .rstable tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    
    .rstable tr td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 9px;
        color: #333;
    }
    
    .rstable th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 9px;
        background: #004287;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f9fbfdc4;
    }
    
    .rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #dae9f3;
    }
    
    .rstable tr td a {
        color: #004287;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
        .rstable table {
            font-size: 15px;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .rstable table {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable thead {
            display: none;
        }
        .rstable td:first-child {
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-grid;
            width: 90%;
        }
        .rstable td {
            text-align: left;
            display: inline-grid;
            width: 26%;
            vertical-align: top;
            color: #333;
            font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable td:before {
            content: attr(data-title);
            font-weight: 500;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: #000;
        }
    }
    
    @media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
        .rstable td {
            width: 23%;
        }
    }
    /* Responsive Table Ends */      
   .arrow-right,
        .arrow-left {
            display: block;
            margin: 10px auto;
            width: 8px;
            height: 8px;
            border-top: 2px solid #000;
            border-left: 2px solid #000;
        }
        
        .arrow-right {
            transform: rotate(135deg);
        }
        
        .arrow-left {
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        
.pagination-container {
        width: calc(100% - 0rem);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 0rem 0;
        justify-content: right;
        /* text-align: center; */
    }

    .pagination-number,
    .pagination-button {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #0085b6;;
        border: none;
        margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 2rem;
        width: 2rem;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
    }

   .newpagination-numbers {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: #333;;
        border: none;
        margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
        height: 2rem;
        width: 2rem;
        line-height: 2rem;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
    }
 .newpagination-numbers:hover {
 background: #34A853;
}
    .pagination-number:hover,
    .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
        color: #fff !important;
        background: #FBBC05;
    }
   
   button.disabled {
    background-color: #c82333; /*Make it whatever color you want*/
    }

    
    .disabled { 
        
        color: #333 !important;
        pointer-events: none !important;
        cursor: not-allowed !important;
        
    }

    span.disabled {
        border-color: #333 !important;
    
    }

    
    .pagination-number.active {
        color: #fff;
        background: #0085b6;
    }
```

```html
                    <div class="result">
                        <div class='canel-trains-grids'>
                            <div class='left-cancel'><span>22 Tech Company Listed</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class='right-cancel'>
                                <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder='Enter Train Number'>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Result Table Starts -->
                   <div class="rstable">
<table id="paginated-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Joined</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th>Contact</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Airi Satou</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Accountant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">No1</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">1</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar1</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">01</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Germany</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome1</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">97</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Angelica Ramos</td>
            <td data-title="Position">CEO</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">2</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar2</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">02</td>
            <td data-title="Country">India</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome2</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">96</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Ashton Cox</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Technical Author</td>
            <td data-title="Office">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">3</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar3</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">03</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Japan</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome3</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">95</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bradley Greer</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Integration Specialist</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">4</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar4</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">04</td>
            <td data-title="Country">UK</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome4</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">94</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brenden Wagner</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Software Engineer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">5</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">05</td>
            <td data-title="Country">USA</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome5</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">93</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Pre-Sales Support</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">6</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">06</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Canada</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome6</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">92</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Bruno Nash</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Sales Assistant</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">7</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">07</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Italy</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome7</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">91 </td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Name">Caesar Vance</td>
            <td data-title="Position">Javascript Developer</td>
            <td data-title="Office">CR</td>
            <td data-title="Extn.">8</td>
            <td data-title="Joined">Mar</td>
            <td data-title="Salary">GKP</td>
            <td data-title="Company">Island Trading</td>
            <td data-title="Contact">08</td>
            <td data-title="Country">Mexico</td>
            <td data-title="Browser">Chrome8</td>
            <td data-title="Platform">Win 10</td>
            <td data-title="Engine">90</td>
            <td data-title="Grade">A</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>

<div style="width: 100%; display: flex;align-items: center;">
             <div style="text-align: left; width: 50%;">
                            <span id="currpagecount">Showing 1 to 2 of </span><span id="totalrowscount">8</span>
                        </div>
    <div class="pagination-container">
        <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-button" aria-label="Previous page" title="Previous page">
            <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="pagination-numbers" class="newpagination-numbers">
        <span id="currentPage"></span>/<span id="pageCount"></span>
        </div>
        <button class="pagination-button" id="next-button" aria-label="Next page" title="Next page">
            <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
                    <!-- Result Table Ends -->
```

Comment: Still have to look more closely, but apparently you are looking for something that is not on the page yet, you should from where you are retrieving data if that is what you want

Answer (score -1):

Your search operation seems to be based on analysing every table row to see if the content matches. However, in real life, you will be getting the displayed data from an API. You would then use this data to populate your table and to perform search operations.

In the following snippet, I have modified you code to use train details stored in an array. The code then dynamically renders the array.

When user searches any train number, we search inside the array as it is computationally cheaper.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .result {
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids {
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel {
        float: left;
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .left-cancel span {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: #34a853;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 8px 8px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        width: auto;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel {
        float: right;
        width: 30%;
        margin-top: 10px;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel label {
        float: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
        line-height: 39px;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: 400;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input {
        width: 230px;
        height: 22px;
        border: 1px solid #dae9f3;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 16px;
        float: right;
      }

      .canel-trains-grids .right-cancel input:focus {
        outline: none;
      }

      /* Responsive Table Start */

      .rstable {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 16px 0px;
      }

      .rstable table {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font-size: 16px;
        width: 100%;
        font-weight: 400;
      }

      .rstable tr {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
      }

      .rstable tr td {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 9px;
        color: #333;
      }

      .rstable th {
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px 9px;
        background: #004287;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .rstable tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f9fbfdc4;
      }

      .rstable tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background: #dae9f3;
      }

      .rstable tr td a {
        color: #004287;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
        .rstable table {
          font-size: 15px;
        }
      }

      @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .rstable table {
          font-size: 16px;
          font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable thead {
          display: none;
        }
        .rstable td:first-child {
          text-align: left;
          display: inline-grid;
          width: 90%;
        }
        .rstable td {
          text-align: left;
          display: inline-grid;
          width: 26%;
          vertical-align: top;
          color: #333;
          font-weight: 400;
        }
        .rstable td:before {
          content: attr(data-title);
          font-weight: 500;
          padding-bottom: 5px;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: #000;
        }
      }

      @media (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 319px) {
        .rstable td {
          width: 23%;
        }
      }
      /* Responsive Table Ends */

      .arrow-right,
      .arrow-left {
        display: block;
        margin: 10px auto;
        width: 8px;
        height: 8px;
        border-top: 2px solid #000;
        border-left: 2px solid #000;
      }

      .arrow-right {
        transform: rotate(135deg);
      }

      .arrow-left {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
      }

      .hidden {
        display: none;
      }

      .pagination-container {
        width: calc(100% - 0rem);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 0;
        padding: 0rem 0;
        justify-content: right;
      }

      .pagination-number,
      .pagination-button {
        font-family: calibri, sans-serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        margin: 0.1rem 0.1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 2rem;
        width: 2rem;
        border-radius: 0.2rem;
      }

      .pagination-number:hover,
      .pagination-button:not(.disabled):hover {
        background: #fff;
      }

      .pagination-number.active {
        color: #fff;
        background: #0085b6;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="result">
      <div class="canel-trains-grids">
        <div class="left-cancel">
          <span>22 Rajdhani Express Trains Listed</span>
        </div>
        <div class="right-cancel">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="myInput"
            placeholder="Enter Train Number"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rstable">
      <table id="paginated-list">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Train</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Zone</th>
            <th>From</th>
            <th>Dep</th>
            <th>To</th>
            <th>Arr</th>
            <th>Dur</th>
            <th>Halts</th>
            <th>Runs On</th>
            <th>Dist</th>
            <th>Speed</th>
            <th>Classes</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="paginated-list-body"></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center">
      <div style="text-align: left; width: 50%">
        <span id="currNumber"></span><span id="rowsNumber"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="pagination-container">
        <button
          class="pagination-button"
          id="prev-button"
          aria-label="Previous page"
          title="Previous page"
          onclick="onPreviousClick()"
        >
          <span class="arrow-left"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="pagination-numbers"></div>
        <button
          class="pagination-button"
          id="next-button"
          aria-label="Next page"
          title="Next page"
          onclick="onNextClick()"
        >
          <span class="arrow-right"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    const columns = [
      { attr: "train" },
      { attr: "type" },
      { attr: "zone" },
      { attr: "from" },
      { attr: "dep" },
      { attr: "to" },
      { attr: "arr" },
      { attr: "dur" },
      { attr: "halts" },
      { attr: "runsOn" },
      { attr: "dist" },
      { attr: "speed" },
      { attr: "classes" },
    ];
    const allDataList = [
      {
        train: "15011 Kashi Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "97 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15012 Pushpak Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "96 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15013 Godan Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "95 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15014 Golden Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "94 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15015 Lucknow Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "93 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15016 SLN Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "92 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15017 Sitapur Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "91 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
      {
        train: "15018 Darbhanga Express",
        type: "SuperFast",
        zone: "CR",
        from: "LTT",
        dep: "15:30",
        to: "GKP",
        arr: "06:15 +1 night",
        dur: "7h 55m",
        halts: "11",
        runsOn: "S - T - T F -",
        dist: "632 km",
        speed: "90 km/hr",
        classes: "SL | 3A | 2A",
      },
    ];

    // These variables store what items need to be rendered in current page
    let startIdx = 0;
    let pageCount = 2;

    // Render the first page.
    renderTableContents(allDataList.slice(startIdx, startIdx + pageCount));
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('input', onSearchTextChange);

    function renderTableContents(dataToRender, hideCurrPageInfo = false) {
      const tableBody = document.getElementById("paginated-list-body");
      tableBody.innerHTML = '';

      dataToRender.forEach((trainItem) => {
        const rowElement = document.createElement("tr");

        columns.forEach((col) => {
          const cellElement = document.createElement("td");
          cellElement.innerText = trainItem[col.attr];
          rowElement.appendChild(cellElement);
        });

        tableBody.appendChild(rowElement);
      });

      const pageInfo = `${Math.round(startIdx / pageCount) + 1}/${allDataList.length / pageCount}`;
      const pageInfoElement = document.getElementById('pagination-numbers');
      pageInfoElement.innerText = pageInfo;

      let currentPageCount = `Showing ${startIdx + 1} to ${startIdx + pageCount} of ${allDataList.length}`;
      if (hideCurrPageInfo) {
        currentPageCount = 'Showing - to - of 8'
      }
      const currentPageCountElement = document.getElementById('currNumber');
      currentPageCountElement.innerText = currentPageCount;
    }

    // Event Handlers
    function onPreviousClick() {
      // Go to previous page only if one exists
      if (startIdx - pageCount >= 0) {
        startIdx = startIdx - pageCount;
      }
      renderTableContents(allDataList.slice(startIdx, startIdx + pageCount));
    }

    function onNextClick() {
      // Go to next page only if one exists
      if (startIdx + pageCount < allDataList.length) {
        startIdx = startIdx + pageCount;
      }
      renderTableContents(allDataList.slice(startIdx, startIdx + pageCount));
    }

    function onSearchTextChange(e) {
      console.log(e);
      const searchText = e.target.value;

      const filteredData = allDataList.filter(item => item.train.indexOf(searchText) != -1);

      // Hide the current page info here, as it doesnt make sense with search results.
      renderTableContents(filteredData, true);
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

For your query regarding displaying the total row count on each page, check out the functions `onPreviousClick` and `onNextClick`. These functions update the variable **startIdx** that point to the element of array from which we will render.

The function `renderTableContents` is responsible for taking an array (individual pages or search result) and rendering it to the screen.

As I mentioned, it is computationally cheaper to search an array instead of the entire DOM. However, if your result contains a lot of rows, it doesn't make sense to do it in the browser. In such a scenario, you will be making an API request to the backend with the search text and rendering that result.